# How to Add a Scrollbar to Window in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, window, vertical-scrolling

I have created a window as follows:

```
Window myWindow = new Window();
```

How can I add a Vertical Scroll Bar to this Windows and make the Scroll Bar only visible if the Height isn't large enough to show all the elements.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You could add a [ScrollViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750665.aspx) element to your window and put the necessary controls into the *ScrollViewer* control.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    ...
</ScrollViewer>
```

Or if you want to code it in the code-behind file you could write

```
ScrollViewer viewer = new ScrollViewer();
viewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
// append scroll viewer to window
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add a scrollbar to a window itself. You can only add scrollbars to controls. I.E. to a grid inside your window.

Example:

```
<Grid  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
       ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
   ...
</Grid>
```

**EDIT:**

Just realized that Window also has a ScrollViewer property. I'm not sure how this property works for a Window and how such a window would look like. Gave it a try, but no scrollbars show up.

**EDIT 2:**

```
ScrollViewer sv = new ScrollViewer();
sv.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
myGrid.Children.Add(sv);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Instead of creating the Grid using XAML, I have created it using Programatically usig Grid. What properties of Grid do I set to get a Scrollbar?

Comment: I don't have a ScrollViewer Property. What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: @Gunner - I am using .NET 3.5 SP1. The ScrollViewer is in System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var xpage = your user control or page to which scroll bar need to be added at runtime

            xpage.SetValue(ScrollViewer.CanContentScrollProperty, true);
            xpage.SetValue(ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibilityProperty, ScrollBarVisibility.Auto);
            xpage.SetValue(ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibilityProperty, ScrollBarVisibility.Auto);

            var scrollViewer = xpage.Content as ScrollViewer;
            if (scrollViewer != null)
            {
                var content = scrollViewer.Content;
                scrollViewer.Content = null;
                xpage.Content = content;
            }
            else
            {
                var content = xpage.Content;
                xpage.Content = null;
                xpage.Content = new ScrollViewer { Content = content };
            }
```