# How to put a scrollbar in windows app .xaml?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

So just creating a basic app, complete noob, how do i scroll

```
<Grid>
   <Textblock>
   <Button>
   <Textblock>
   <Button>
   <Textblock>
   <Button>
   <Textblock>
   <Button>
    ......
</Grid>
```

just a  basic grid with many textblock and buttons , now as it doesnt fit on the screen , how do i make a scrollbar appear to scroll downwards.

Comment: No offense, but I just googled "How to put a scrollbar in XAML" and  found a lot of answers, including [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068860/how-to-add-a-scrollbar-to-window-in-c-sharp).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enabling Scrollbar in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736153/enabling-scrollbar-in-wpf)

Comment: error occurs " content can only be set once"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a `ScrollViewer` control, and (since the ScrollViewer allows only one content element) some layout container as, for example, a `StackPanel`. Example:

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Textblock>
            <Button>
            <Textblock>
            <Button>
            <Textblock>
            <Button>
            <Textblock>
            <Button>
            ......
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This is correct, but don't use a stackpanel, use a `DockPanel`. `DockPanel` will adapt the correct height, whereas `StackPanel` will just keep going and never get a scrollbar unless you specify a `Height` for it.

Comment: thanks, it is now scrollable but the layout changed completely, the textblocks and buttons are like only two of them in one screen.

Comment: @DLeh how do i use the dockpanel

Comment: Error 1 DockPanel is not supported in a Windows App project.

Comment: Sorry, I guess `DockPanel`s are in WPF. Maybe you don't need it with the way `StackPanel`s are done in Windows Apps. Use google, there will be plenty of other answers about how to make a scroll bar.