# Exit the screen in WPF C #

Tags: wpf

I need a hint as to how to get the user out of the screen in the WPF window. I made a window that does not fit on the screen and needs to be scrolled so that more data can be added, but I have no idea how to do it. Or maybe I can add a slider to see a further label?

Comment: You should show us what you've already tried, show code examples and any error message you're having.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [scroll-viewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/scrollviewer-overview) control. see this [How to add scroll viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068860/how-to-add-a-scrollbar-to-window-in-c-sharp). Hope it helps.
**In XAML**

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    Put other xaml content here..
</ScrollViewer>
```

or you can show **Scrollbar in `Grid`**

```
<Grid  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
       ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
   ...
</Grid>
```

**Or in Program**

```
ScrollViewer sv = new ScrollViewer();
sv.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
myGrid.Children.Add(sv);
```